# How to make Zapier Webhooks work as fufillment in API.AI

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, zapier, actions-on-google

I am experimenting with an API.AI agent. I want the responses to an intent to be fulfilled by webhooks.

I created a Zap that catch Webhooks as a trigger. The "Catch hook" trigger gave me an URL such as https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/1111111/9aaaaa/ that i entered in the API.AI fulfillment.
API.AI sends correctly the JSON to this URL, and the Zap is triggered, receiving the following example JSON:

```html
result__fulfillment__messages: speech: 
type: 0
id: 8551d99c-1ce9-4a0c-b24e-27d4c2090dbf
result__actionIncomplete: False
result__action: Trip-recommendations
result__resolvedQuery: all inclusive
result__metadata__intentId: 314e8e2f-312f-4ebd-93e1-c92da8648725
result__metadata__webhookForSlotFillingUsed: false
status__code: 200
timestamp: 2017-05-16T00:04:37.773Z
result__metadata__intentName: trip-recommendations
result__parameters__trip-who: family
result__parameters__trip-interest: all inclusive
status__errorType: success
lang: en
result__score: 1.0
result__source: agent
result__metadata__webhookUsed: true
sessionId: e28bd01f-2852-4c0c-98d8-ea03d58d87fa
Fields with no value:
result__parameters__trip-destinations
result__fulfillment__speech
result__contexts
result__speech
result__parameters__trip-recomendation-Country
result__parameters__date
result__parameters__unit-currency
result__parameters__date-period
```

Now i am trying to send a response in the second step of the Zap so as my API.AI agent use the response from the webhook as a fulfillment of the intent.

To do that i configured the second step of the Zap as a Webhooks Custom Request action with the following parameters:

- URL: same as the URL entered in API.AI fulfillment menu https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/1111111/9aaaaa/
- Payload Type: Json
- Method: POST
- Data:

```html
unflatten: yes
url: https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/1111111/9aaaaa/ 
    "fulfillment": {
  "speech": "Today in Boston: Fair, the temperature is 37 F",
  "source": "apiai-weather-webhook-sample",
  "displayText": "Today in Boston: Fair, the temperature is 37 F"
}
method: POST
pass_through:
```

But when when i test the agent in Google Assistant simulator the response to the intent is always "I am sorry, the agentname is not available right now"

Does anyone can point me at what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Zapier's webhook triggers always respond with a JSON payload containing the same set of status-related properties (basically a confirmation that the webhook request was received and nothing more). There's no way to change that response data, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Do you know any other automation service or something similar that would allow to manage that response data for non-programmers folks?